# How to use YUI3 gallery: trying to find a working example

Tags: javascript, yui3

I have found a large and well-structured [github repository](https://github.com/yui/yui3-gallery) for yui3 gallery. However, I was surprised to see only raw `*.js` files [inside](https://github.com/yui/yui3-gallery/tree/master/build/gallery-carousel-anim). I have visited an [official site](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/carousel-anim) too. Most of examplead are [very old](http://erisds.co.uk/resources/yui-carousel-demo-1) or DEAD.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something. Such a big project should have a working demo page, but I have not found any. Is it so terrible that I have to compile every example manually if I want to try?

Comment: There is also unofficial site, but it looks like "back to the 90's" http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~rdhyee/yui/examples/carousel/csl_circular.html

Answer (score 3):

You are not the only one that felt somewhat frustrated by the YUI3 Gallery, though you fare worst than others since, from the links you list, you came in through the back door, the repository, instead of the actual [landing page](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/).

The quality of the offerings in the gallery is very varied and they are unrated.  To fix that, in a few weeks, a new catalog will be available which will have some sort of rating for the entries so it is easier to see how good and well maintained the modules are.  This, of course, does not guarantee that any carousel will make it into the decently rated, if that is what you need.  Until then, if you cannot wait, all you can do is check them out.